# Наиболее быстрый способ проверки существования ресурса

Tags: php, http

Как можно максимально быстро проверить некий интернет ресурс на существование, т.е другими словами, ссылку на валидность?

**Я пробовал так:**

```
...
 // коды состояния HTTP 1.1, свидетельствующие об успехе или псевдоуспехе
$SUCCESS_STATE = array( 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 226, 301, 302, 303, 305, 307);
$headers = @get_headers($url); // запрос к ресурсу
// ищем первое совпадение с кодом состояния псевдоуспеха.
for($i=0;$i<count($SUCCESS_STATE);$i++) 
if(strstr($headers[0],$SUCCESS_STATE[$i])) {return true; break;}
...
```

Но если, скажем, надо проверить более 3-4 ресурсов подряд, то процесс этот нудно затягивается, что не есть хорошо. **Как бы вы поступили?**

---

Кто-нибудь поможет? =)

Comment: Не занимался подобным, но предполагаю что ответа 200 хватило бы!

Comment: @Palmervan, так не идет, потому что, допустим, ссылка такого вида:

     http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B7&lr=213

Указывает не вполне существующий ресурс, но возвращает код состояния из подгруппы кодов состояния перенаправления 3xx, так как содержит GET-запрос.

---
Код состояния 200 возвращают ТОЛЬКО статические ссылки вида:

    http://site.com/aa/bb/cc

Comment: попробуй file_get_contents()

Comment: @johniek_comp, это, к сожалению, будет еще дольше =). Потому что сначала будет отправлен все тот же запрос на получения ответа от сервера, а потом будет произведена попытка считывания несуществующих данных( если ресурса нет ), что займет почти двойное время! А мне надо бы узнавать валидность/невалидность за линейное время...

Comment: Почему-то не могу написать комментарий к вопросу. Спрошу тут: уточните, что вам нужно проверить? Существование конкретной страницы по конкретному адресу? Существование сайта по этому адресу? Существование сервера, на котором хостится этот сайт? Немного не точный вопрос.

Comment: Так ссылку на валидность или ресурс на существание? Валидность ссылки - это существование страницы (т.е. проверка на не 404). А проверка ресурса на существование - это проверить существует ли в целом сайт. Формулируйте точнее.

Comment: @Саша Андрошук, а вы подумали о ошибках со стороны сервера - кодов состояния 5хх ? Вы вспомнили одну ошибку из ошибок со стороны клиента, но ошибок с кодом 4xx гораздо больше! Так как в сумме количество 5xx + 4xx кодов состояний гораздо больше, чем 2xx + 3xx кодов, то было бы разумно сверяться со вторым вариантом! Думаю, вопросы отпали.

Comment: 404 я привел как пример. Но всеравно мне суть вашего вопроса не ясна.

Comment: Открывается - это что? Существует он или нет? (тогда в этом случае вообще рассматривать код HTTP не имеет смысла)

Comment: Изучайте, как работает протокол HTTP, @Саша Андрошук

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php), выполняющий [параллельные запросы](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) пачками.

[Опции](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), которые понадобятся:

- `CURLOPT_NOBODY = TRUE` — запрашивать только HEAD;
- `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT = TRUE` — заголовки включить в ответ;
- `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = TRUE` — вместо вывода на экран, результат возвращать.

Распараллеливание потребует больше памяти, но здорово ускорит задачу. Я использую такие параллельные запросы при обращении к Амазоновским сервисам, по 50 одновременно. Ускорение ощутимо: на 50 запросов всего 4 секунды, вместо 192 (реальные цифры профайлинга).

Comment: @sergiks - вы правы, напрочь вылетело из головы в связи с тем, что крайне давно применял. `cyrl_multi_*` - это действительно именно то, что поможет адекватно решить эту задачу.

Comment: Да, cURL здесь правда больше всего подходит. У меня тоже как-то вылетело это из головы.

Answer (score -2):

попробуй **[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)**

```
<?php
if(!file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/'))
{
    echo 'Такого адреса нет';
}
```

Comment: Говорю же: это еще дольше!

Comment: @johniek_comp - почитайте о том, что именно делает `file_get_contents` и что делает `get_headers`, быть может поймете почему вы не правы.